# How to import one android.mk file into another android.mk file?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to import one ndroid.mk file into another android.mk file
 I have android.mk file in which i have

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := importfile
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libEDSDK.a
/*LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/EDSDK $(LOCAL_PATH)/EDSDKErrors $(LOCAL_PATH)/EDSDKTypes*/
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
TARGET_PLATFORM:=android-8
TARGET_ARCH_ABI:=armeabi
TARGET_ABI:=$(TARGET_PLATFORM)-$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

I want to import this android.mk file into another android.mk file

```
$NDK_MODULE_PATHjni/module1/Android.mk:
 LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := EDSK
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := sample.c
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := EDSDK.lib
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
TARGET_PLATFORM:=android-8
TARGET_ARCH_ABI:=armeabi
TARGET_ABI:=$(TARGET_PLATFORM)-$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)
$(call import-module,importfile)
```

but  while   building  this i got error i.e

```
Android NDK: jni/Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'importfile' in import path    
Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined ?    
Android NDK: The following directories were searched:    
Android NDK:
```

please help.

Comment: I think this one should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942730/android-ndk-how-to-include-android-mk-into-another-android-mk?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Answers to NDK build questions which explicitly use $(LOCAL_PATH) are not correct (I don't know if they were always incorrect, but they definitely do not work for NDK version r8b). You should not prepend paths with $(LOCAL_PATH) - the build system automatically prefixes $(LOCAL_PATH) - hence these scripts prefix LOCAL_PATH twice and fail. This mistake is repeated all over Stack Overflow but I can't go through and correct every answer about the Android build system, so I have posted this in one of the most recent posts on the subject.

I would recommend people answering questions should be using the latest version of the NDK tools, or else qualify their answers with the version they are using.

Answer (score 1):

Basically do it like this:

```
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/libos/Android.mk
```

This is just normal makefile syntax (See here:http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html)