# Android NDK: code under sub-directory isn't built at all

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, makefile, multiple-makefiles

In my Android NDK project, I have the following structure:

```
jni/    
  Android.mk
  ...            (more source files)

  new-lib/
     Android.mk
      ...            (more source files)
```

In the top level **Android.mk** I have `include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)` as the last line. I suppose now all the native codes including those under **new-lib/** should get built when run `ndk-build`.

But when I run `ndk-build` command under project root path, only the top level native codes get built, the native code in subdir **new-lib/** isn't built at all. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I only work with one Android.mk in which I define all include folders, but I think [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942730/android-ndk-how-to-include-android-mk-into-another-android-mk) you'll find what you need. For what I understand, you need to make sure you are using the `LOCAL_PATH` in **all** your Android.mk files like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
```