# Android NDK - Build app with mulltiple NDK build

Tags: android, android-ndk

Is it possible to link multiple native libraries(written in C) in build.gradle like this:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path 'src/main/c/Lib1Android.mk'
        path 'src/main/c/Lib2Android.mk'
    }
}
```

When I use this my JNI file can't see native functions from Lib1 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [NdkBuild doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/NdkBuild) you need to specify only the root ndk-build script but in it you can call any number of other `Android.mk` files (here is discussed how to do this [Android NDK: how to include Android.mk into another Android.mk (hierarchical project structure)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942730/android-ndk-how-to-include-android-mk-into-another-android-mk-hierarchical-pro)).